# What is this "score" actually? extra trees classifier with sklearn/Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I use `ExtraTreesClassifier` to find out which attributes are more important in my dataset. As a result, it returns me a score value (for example every attribute has a score like `0.037`, `0.025`, `0.012` etc..), what exactly does this score mean?

**Edited: I am actually searching how is it calculating? Which formula gives me score?**

```
model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(dataValues, dataTargetEncoded)

feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_,index=dataValues.columns)
feat_importances.nlargest(25).plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scores themselves are calculated in [feature_importances_](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/e070b7451707e6bd1c1119c64bccd34df31fffe6/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L354) of `BaseForest` class. They are calculated as

```
np.mean(all_importances, axis=0, dtype=np.float64) / np.sum(all_importances)
```

where `all_importances` is an array of `feature_importances_` of estimators of [`ExtraTreesClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html). Number of estimators is defined by parameter `n_estimators` of 
`ExtraTreesClassifier`. There are 10 estimators by default (The default value of n_estimators will change from 10 in version `0.20` to 100 in version `0.22`):

```
est = [estimator for estimator in model.estimators_]

est[0]
Out[57]: 
ExtraTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
          max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
          min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
          min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
          min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, random_state=1045388471,
          splitter='random')

len(est)
Out[58]: 10
```

So, `all_importances` looks like

```
[x.feature_importances_ for x in est]
Out[59]: 
[array([0., 0., 1.]),
 array([0., 0., 1.]),
 array([0., 0., 1.]),
 array([0.33333333, 0.        , 0.66666667]),
 array([0.11111111, 0.88888889, 0.        ]),
 array([0., 1., 0.]),
 array([0., 0., 1.]),
 array([0., 1., 0.]),
 array([0., 0., 1.]),
 array([0.33333333, 0.66666667, 0.        ])]
```

`feature_importances_` for each estimator is computed by [`compute_feature_importances`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/e070b7451707e6bd1c1119c64bccd34df31fffe6/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L1053) method of [`Tree`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/e070b7451707e6bd1c1119c64bccd34df31fffe6/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L506) class written on Cython. It is computed by iterating through each node of tree nodes, adding to corresponding feature:

```
feature_importances_[node.feature] += node.weighted_n_node_samples * node.impurity -
                                      left.weighted_n_node_samples * left.impurity -
                                      right.weighted_n_node_samples * right.impurity
```

where `weighted_n_node_samples` and `impurity` are arrays with node parameters:

```
est[0].tree_.feature
Out[60]: array([ 2,  2, -2, -2, -2], dtype=int64)

est[0].tree_.weighted_n_node_samples
Out[61]: array([4., 2., 1., 1., 2.])

est[0].tree_.impurity
Out[62]: array([0.375, 0.5  , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ])
```

`feature_importances_` are normalized after calculation. You can see raw values by calling `compute_feature_importances` with parameter `normalize=False`:

```
est[3].tree_.compute_feature_importances(normalize=False)
Out[63]: array([0.125, 0.   , 0.25 ])

est[3].tree_.compute_feature_importances()
Out[64]: array([0.33333333, 0.        , 0.66666667])
```

Comment: You both are my heroes. Thaank you so much

Answer (score 2):

In one line:

The higher the score, more important is the corresponding feature.

From [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#feature-importance-evaluation):

The relative rank (i.e. depth) of a feature used as a decision node in a tree can be used to assess the relative importance of that feature with respect to the predictability of the target variable. **Features used at the top of the tree contribute to the final prediction decision of a larger fraction of the input samples**. The expected fraction of the samples they contribute to can thus be used as an estimate of the relative importance of the features.

In scikit-learn, **the fraction of samples a feature contributes to**  is combined with **the decrease in impurity from splitting them** to create a normalized estimate of the predictive power of that feature.

You can find more details in

> G. Louppe, “Understanding Random Forests: From Theory to Practice”,
>   PhD Thesis, U. of Liege, 2014.

From the above thesis:

[image]

From Documentation:

The weighted impurity decrease equation is the following based on the code:

```
Feature of importance of feature X_i 
    = Sum of the following value for all nodes, in which X_i is the splitting features

       N_t / N *impurity - N_t_R / N_t * right_impurity
                        - N_t_L / N_t * left_impurity
```

where `N` is the total number of samples, `N_t` is the number of
samples at the current node, `N_t_L` is the number of samples in the
left child, and `N_t_R` is the number of samples in the right child.
`N`, `N_t`, `N_t_R` and `N_t_L` all refer to the weighted sum,
if `sample_weight` is passed.

For an ensemble of trees, the feature importance of all trees are averaged to get the overall model's feature importance.

Comment: Its stuck on my mind, how is score calculating? Which formula gives me score? Can you help me for this?